# Deleted question with un-deleted answers?

Tags: support, specific-question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157125/do-we-really-need-the-subjective-tag-and-is-it-commonly-mis-used

turned up with an answer in the VLQ queue. Is this a database glitch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Must have been a bug at the time of deletion, where only the question got deleted but the answers were not.

I've undeleted and re-deleted and all well in the world.