# Will a deleted question get un-deleted if an answer gets enough un-delete votes?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, vote-to-undelete

I happen to see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30818920/2333214) from [this Meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323738/2333214). The question has an un-delete vote and an upvoted answer, among others.

This made me wonder what happens if an upvoted answer alone gets enough un-delete votes? Will the question get un-deleted as well? What about the other answers that got deleted along with the question's deletion? Will those get reversed?

I found a somewhat related [bug report](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254354/2333214) while posting this.

Comment: No it won't :-)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you try to undelete-vote an answer on a deleted question, you'll get this message:

> *Answers to deleted questions cannot be undeleted*

So, an answer on a deleted question can't get undelete votes.
Any existing undelete votes on said answer, were cast before the question was deleted.

Comment: Are you sure about that? [Some fun](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/30123253#30123253) happened in chat one day resulting in [that](http://i.stack.imgur.com/P2Glm.png) (undeleted answer on a deleted question).

Comment: Eeeeh... Bug? :D

Comment: @Tunaki Only moderators can vote to undelete, and it's a bit of a non-issue because the system will automatically delete answers on a deleted question on a cycle that runs like every hour or so, so it wouldn't stay undeleted for long. In fact, this happens when a migration gets rejected. The Community user auto-undeletes all the answers because of the rejection, and they all get deleted again a short while later.

Comment: Ha, thanks for the clarification @animuson!